# External website inaccessible, within domain due to a forward lookup zone with the same domain name as the website's domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

We have a public facing website eg. https://www.abc.qa (hosted by a vendor) and we have a forward Lookup zone in our internal DNS named eg. abc.qa. The forward lookup zone was created, so that our web application can be accessed using eg. https://hostname.abc.qa URL. The primary internal domain is eg. abc.local.

We are facing two issue due to this kind of setup - 1) Our external website is inaccessible internally within the domain (with or without www), however externally it works fine. 2) The web application is accessible internally. However, this web application is integrated with the website and so it communicates with the website through webservice and this communication does not works.

I researched about similar issues and found various solutions predominantly the one's below - 
1) Adding netsh interface portproxy 
2) Adding DNS delegation 
3) Adding A or C record in DNS for the website.

None of the above works. I don't know why #1 doesn't works, but #2 and #3 are not applicable, as our website is hosted by a third party and they say the IP range changes frequently, so i cannot hardcode the IP.

Is there any other workaround apart from adding a subdomain or changing the internal forward lookup zone named abc.qa?

Comment: Your site is not reacahble externally. Your DNS is misconfigured. The declared nameservers in your domain registration refused queries for your domain.

Comment: Hi Michael, if you're talking about www.abc.qa, it's just a dummy website name, i entered as an example. Sorry for not making it clear in the question.

Comment: You should not use other people's domains as examples. It will only confuse everybody. Use your actual domain mane instead, if possible.

Comment: Got it Michael, will keep that in mind, going forward. For now, i've edited my original post to indicate, those are dummy names.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. Our website is hosted on AWS and with cloudfront in middle, it serves the cached the content. To resolve the issue, i created a cName record on our DNS server pointing it to our cloudfront host. The other solution was to point it directly to the admin portal of our website.